# null pointer exception with string tokenizer

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I have local String array and i try to fill it with the returned tokens from `Stringtokenizer.nexttoken`

when i was declaring the string array as local variable i got i warning

```
Null pointer access: The variable words can only be null at this location
```

so i make the sting array as field in the class and i instantiate it

like this

```
 String[] words =new String [12000];
```

the warning disappear but i still get the same exception

```
StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(text);


int j=0;
while(st.hasMoreTokens())
{
  words[j++]=st.nextToken();    

}
```

i use callable and future to execute the part of code that contain this block

and the exception that i get it is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
```

{the code work perfectly when i use `split` method to get the tokens array}

Comment: What is the value of `text`?

Comment: it's take it's value from text file and i'm sure that is not null

Comment: This code should work fine providing the variable text isn't null. Are you sure you're reading from the text file correctly? I have a feeling that you need to provide more context (more code) in order for your problem to be properly evaluated.

Comment: yes i'm sure i tried to debug my code and i saw that text is not null beside that i used text.split and it's work

Comment: Do you, by any chance, initialize the words array in one thread, and use it in another? Could you show us what exactly does the callable do and how you invoke it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem fixed but replacing the String array with the `arraylist<String>`

```
while(st.hasMoreTokens())
    {
     words.add(st.nextToken()); 

    }
```